# Override CSS-Grid property for specific child

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I am new in CSS-Grid topic, I created a header for a website with the help of **GRID**, I created header with logo , navBar , searchbar , button with grid

```
.header {
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 0.1fr 0.5fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 70px;
    align-items:center;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

Now these last two properties **align-items** and **justify-items** are apply for all ie, for logo , navbar , searchbar , button.
*My problem is* :I want to override this **justify-items:center** property 
 to **justify-items:flex-start** for navBar only. So who can I do this?

Here is screenshot of header:

[image: here is screenshot of header]

Comment: `.navBar { justify-self: flex-start }`. It overrides `justify-items` coming from the parent. No other changes needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing in pure CSS, you can add another line that is more specific, like this

```
.header .navBar {
    justify-items:flex-start;
}
```

This will take priority over the previous css style you have. Generally speaking the more specific styles are applied first.

Comment: I  tried this but this is not working, I also applied  "!important " but this still not work.